# Unable to resolve host for http connection

Tags: android

I am trying out a simple http connection through this program but getting resourcenotfoundexception, Unable to resolve host "www.google.com": No address associated with hostname.What is the reason behind this ?

```
public class HttpClientActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

//      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
//              .permitAll().build();
//      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

//      connect();

        new Connection().execute();

    }

    private class Connection extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            connect();
            return null;
        }

    }

    private void connect() {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Guys please check this out making a http connection not seem to working via emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify that you are allowed to access the internet from your APP.

The permission for that is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Make sure you have the below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**EDIT**   If still not working try this code

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000);
urlc.connect();
Log.i(Tag,Integer.toString(urlc.getResponseCode()));
```

Comment: can you please help me out here,not working for me still

Comment: may I know what error are you getting. Can you post you LogCat because if you are using this code then the error will be different

Comment: I tried this code also i am getting an error ResourceNotFound and unable to resolve host ,address not found

Comment: I believe you are using Emulator. as mentioned in your comment. Try seeing if any webpage using a browser opens by emulator. Or else it is just that your internet connection in the emulator is not turned on

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/http-connect-example-in-android-development/ i tried working same has in this,working out now thanks a lot

Comment: Just wondering is it possible to add a link as a webservice and create an object for the service in the app then call through that object in android ??

Comment: Yes you can do that.. I havent tried creating webservice.. But yes i did create a `Service` in  app then called the android object